# Azure Data factory - How to convert data time to some specific format in pipeline expression builder?

Tags: azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

Input:
"firstRow": {
"flag": false,
"WindowStart": "2022-12-23:18:00:000Z"

I'm using the below format,
formatDateTime(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.windowStart,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm')

but its throwing an error as

Operation on target Copy_staging_to_raw failed: In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '2022-12-23:18:00:000Z' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format

Could you please help me what was the mistake on this?

Comment: I think `2022-12-23:18:00:000Z` this is not the valid date time string. when I checked with a Date time string like this https://i.imgur.com/O5wUciL.png which I took from `@utcnow()`, it gave me the desired format result with the above expression. https://i.imgur.com/jJLpHQ2.png.

Comment: Please do not use the tag [azure-pipelines] for questions related to Azure Data Factory pipelines. [azure-pipelines] is for questions related to Microsoft's Azure DevOps pipelines feature.

Answer (score 0):

> Operation on target Copy_staging_to_raw failed: In function
> 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string
> '2022-12-23:18:00:000Z' was not valid. The datetime string must match
> ISO 8601 format

The error message shows your provided date time string '2022-12-23:18:00:000Z'is not valid for ISO 8601 format.

the ISO 8601 timestamp normally looks like this:

```
String dateString = "2019-09-26T07:58:30.996+0200"
```

This string is now structured in the date format YYYY-MM-DD. The delimiter for the time is “T” and the time format is hh:mm:ss plus the UTC suffix .sssz. The complete format is therefore: YYY-MM-DD “T” hh:mm:ss.SSSZ.

You could use this [converter tool](https://www.timestamp-converter.com/) for the convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following dynamic content instead, to get the desired result.

- The following is the sample of lookup output same as yours:

[image]

Using string and collection functions, I have converted the lookup output data to ISO 8601 format string and converted it to `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm` format:

```
@formatDateTime(concat(first(array(split(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.windowStart,':'))),'T',join(take(skip(array(split(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.windowStart,':')),1),2),':')),'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm')
```

[image]